# Скрипт обратного отсчета

Tags: cron, ajax, php, javascript, mysql

Делаю аукцион, как сделать правильно таймер до завершения торгов? Необходимо закрывать лот каждый час, после этого отправлять письмо победителю и затем заново открыть отсчет (с таким же временем). Подойдет ли для этих целей просто крон? То есть каждый час запускать скрипт, который и будет их закрывать и отправлять письма?  Если возможно, подскажите сам таймер, который подойдет для таких целей.

Comment: Как вариант: в js - использовать setInterval раз в секунду (ну, можно и поумнее логику) - отправлять на сервер запрос -> "Живёт ли наш аукцион или уже нет".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы выполнять действия по закрытию лота/отправке письма – крон, конечно же.

Для точности клиентам нужен единый общий таймер на сервере. Клиенты при подключении запрашивают сервер и получают количество секунд до окончания аукциона, сопоставляют со своими часами и ведут обратный отсчёт, уже ориентируясь на свои часы. Собираетесь ли вы синхронизировать время с сервером супер-точно?

Если важна точность меньше секунды, возможность отправить заявку за полсекунды до окончания — смотрите игровые технологии, socket.io, wamp.ws.

Таймер обратного отсчёта – скриптов полно. Если будете сами писать, учтите, что таймеры JS не точны, и лучше почаще вызывать события и "смотреть" на часы компьютера, [например](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/2oub51pa/).

Answer (score 0):

Таймера, кроме JS'а, ты не напишешь. Думаю, крон все равно лучшее решение, скрипт запускаешь каждую 1-5 минут и проверяешь через БД, что есть закрыть, а что есть открыть, и все.